# Python : except OSError, e:

Tags: python, sst

I'm currently developing a website with the SST - Web Test Framework (i'm very beginner) but I have a problem with python

I used this Link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sst/0.2.2

I m using - Python 3.6.4 and SST - Web Test Framework- Latest Version: 0.2.4

My Code is:

```
from sst.actions import *
go_to('http://www.google.com/')
```

Error is:

```
C:\Python\scrapy-master\Projects>python proxyhar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "proxyhar.py", line 1, in <module>
from sst.actions import *
File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\sst\actions.py", line 274, in <module>
except OSError, e:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone suggest me how to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: That is deprecated Python 2 syntax. Replace it with `except OSError as e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 3 has changed how this expression should be written.  [From the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement), it is now `except OSError as e`.

Note that in Python 2, [both comma and `as` were permitted](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement).

Comment: What is python's work around for this issue?