# Error Installing Hachoir-metadata |Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in...\hachoir-metda

Tags: python, anaconda, hachoir-parser

I am installing hachoir-metadata from reference[3]. I have completed the following for the installation of hachoir-metadata:

```
conda create -n hachoir-metadata pip python=3.5 
activate hachoir-metadat
pip install --upgrade hachoir-metadata
```

I am using the software versions below:

Python Version 3.5.5
Anaconda: 3.6.5

I get an error stating Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in...\hachoir-metda which is shown below. 
[image: Anaconda Command Prompt]

I have completed the following in attempt to fix the problem:

1)Installed setuptools

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools[1]
```

2)Installed ipykernel

```
conda create -n ipykernel pip python=3.5 

activate ipykernel

pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Non of the above work.
Firstly, when analyzing the error it is due to a syntax issue. Therefore, could the error be caused by the fact that the Python version is incompatible(i.e. hachoir-metadata uses an old version of python but this should not be the case right)?

What can be done to solve this issue?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm79z.png) https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/418

[2] http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

[3] https://pypi.org/project/hachoir-metadata/#description

Comment: According to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053865/python-except-oserror-e   it is a version incompatibility issue. However, to go through each line in the module an convert each line of code is not feasible. What is the work around this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this it what I discovered (NB: that I am new to python), hachoir metadata works with python 2 and can not work with python 3+.

There are a few options to address this:

1)Conversion of 2.x code to 3.x for pure Python is generally a straightforward mechanical translation.  There's a program called 2to3 .

```
 Step 1) open command prompt and open that folder in command prompt then 
 type python C:/Python35/Tools/Scripts/2to3.py -w yourfile name [1]
```

2)You can also Port codes from python 2 to python 3 [2]

3)I also found this,Hachoir3 is written for Python 3.3+, it uses the new yield from syntax.[3]

Lucky Us! Guess I'm going with option 3.

[1] https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html

[2] https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

[3] http://pydoc.net/hachoir3/3.0a2/

[4] https://docs.python.org/3/howto/cporting.html#cporting-howto