# How can I solve this orange installation with pip error?

Tags: python

Collecting Orange

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/43/61/29c81c53504fb4c774eaec5218ca39f5d2625a61f0f6a52c61097be17f1c/Orange-2.7.8.tar.gz (15.0MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 15.0MB 1.8MB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-install-gz6v8uk6/Orange/setup.py", line 261
    except OSError, ex:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-gz6v8uk6/Orange/
```

please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u try doing `sudo` ?

Comment: @thaingi Did you use `pip install orange3`

Comment: I use sudo.When pip install orange3,fastTSNE/quad_tree.c:28:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: I've used the command `pip3 install orange3` and works.

Comment: @thaingi That error is easy to solve, just install Python development packages. Python.h is a header file in Python source code in such packages. Apparently Orange 3 needs to compile some C extensions and it needs to have Python source code for this.

Comment: @thaingi On Debian/Ubuntu that would be something like `apt build-dep python`, or see on the web what packages are required to compile Python from source code and install those.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me and it was a version problem. This procedure solved the issue:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip3 install orange3
```

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago, Python 3 has changed how this expression should be written.

It changed to `except OSError as e`.
Source: [Python : except OSError, e:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053865/python-except-oserror-e)

An alternative to getting rid of it is to install orange3 instead of orange.